# SVN: '0x00400039: Collecting Resources'

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

I convert a static project to javascript project in Eclipse IDE.

Now some `*.js` file cannot be committed and throw the error below:

```
SVN: '0x00400039: Collecting Resources' operation finished with error: null java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Have you tried with svn command line ?

Comment: Can you tell me the version of Eclipse IDE that you are running. I think this bug was solved in an update.

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove
SpringSource Tool Suite 

Version: 2.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201205071000

Comment: It may be worth testing the current version 3.0.0 and see if that does the trick. There is a milestone build of 3.1.0 but test the stable version first. Good luck

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a java implementation of svn, it has probably a compatibility problem with the eclipse core, or with your command line svn client.

I suggest you to commit this files from command line, and then re-create your project from svn. Or backup the not commitable files, delete them from your project, do a full update-commit, copy the files back, and to an update-commit again.

Eclipse has more svn packages (a pure java implementation and a wrapper to the svn library in C), for a longterm solution I suggest you to switch to the other.

You should yet check, if the metadata format of your svn in your eclipse, and your command line svn are compatible. It changes quiet often.